# BST assignment operator and copyTree function not workng

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm at a loss on whats up with my BST. For some reason when I try to use the assignment operator it just doesn't work. When I look at the debugger, I get the message `-var-create: unable to create variable object`

Otherwise, when going through the logic on the debugger, it all seems to loop through correctly. Just without setting the root to anything.

This is my main code that I'm using to test it.

```cpp
#include "BST.h"

int main() {
    Bst<int> test1;
    Bst<int> test2;

    test1.Insert(1);
    test1.Insert(2);
    test1.Insert(3);
    test1.Insert(4);
    test1.Insert(5);

    test2 = test1;

    std::vector<int> testVec;

    return 0;
}
```

And this is my bst.h

```cpp
//
// Created by niamh on 11/06/2022.
//

#ifndef UNTITLED_BST_H
#define UNTITLED_BST_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

/**
 * @struct The node structure
 * @tparam T
 */
template <class T>
struct node
{
    T data; // this will become type T later on
    node<T>* left = nullptr;
    node<T>* right = nullptr;

    int height;
};

/**
 * @class BST
 * @brief The binary search tree class
 * @tparam T
 */
template <class T>
class Bst
{
public:
    Bst();
    ~Bst();
    Bst(const Bst<T>& other);
    Bst& operator=(Bst<T>& other);

    void Insert(T data);
    void InOrder(void (*process)(T & , std::vector<T> &), std::vector<T> &dataVec);
    void PostOrder(void (*process)(T& node));
    void PreOrder(void (*process)(T& node));
    bool Search(T data);
    void DeleteTree();

private:
    node<T>* root;

    node<T>* CreateNode(T data);

    node<T>* InsertPriv(T data, node<T>* ptr);
    void InOrderPriv(node<T> *ptr, void (*process)(T &, std::vector<T> &), std::vector<T> & dataVec);
    void PostOrderPriv(node<T>* ptr, void (*process)(T& node));
    void PreOrderPriv(node<T>* ptr, void (*process)(T& node));
    bool SearchPriv(node<T>* ptr, T data);
    void Delete(node<T>* &ptr);
    void CopyTree(node<T>* lhsRoot, node<T>* rhsRoot);

    int max(int a, int b);
    node<T>* rightRotate(node<T>* y);
    node<T>* leftRotate(node<T>* x);
};

/**
 * @brief The default constructor for a BST object
 * @tparam T
 */
template <class T>
Bst<T>::Bst()
{
    root = NULL;
}

/**
 * @brief The destructor for a BST object
 * @tparam T
 */
// destructor
template <class T>
Bst<T>::~Bst()
{
    Delete(this->root);
}

/**
 * @brief Deep copies the values of one BST to the location of another
 * @tparam T
 * @param otherTree
 */
template <class T>
Bst<T>::Bst(const Bst<T> &otherTree)
{
    if(otherTree.root == nullptr)
    {
        root = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        CopyTree(root, otherTree.root);
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Creates a node
 * @tparam T
 * @param data The data to be stored in the node
 * @return Node pointer
 */
// create node (CreateLeaf)
template <class T>
node<T>* Bst<T>::CreateNode(T data) // data will become type T
{
    node<T>* temp = new node<T>;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->height = 1;

    return temp;
}

/**
 * @brief FROM PROGRAMIZ - Get the balance factor of each node
 * @param N
 * @return
 */
template <class T>
int getBalanceFactor(node<T>* N) {
    if (N == NULL)
        return 0;
    return height(N->left) -
           height(N->right);
}

/**
 * Adds a node to the BST
 * @tparam T
 * @param data
 */
template <class T>
void Bst<T>::Insert(T data) {

    root = InsertPriv(data, this->root);
}

/**
 * Inserts the node and data into the tree
 * @tparam T
 * @param data The data that is to be inserted
 * @param ptr
 */
template <class T>
node<T>* Bst<T>::InsertPriv(T data, node<T> *ptr) {
    // Find the correct postion and insert the node

    if(this->root == NULL)
    {
        return CreateNode(data);
    }
    else if(data < ptr->data)
    {
        if(ptr->left != NULL)
        {
            ptr->left = InsertPriv(data, ptr->left);
        }
        else
        {
            ptr->left = CreateNode(data);
        }
    }
    else if(data > ptr->data)
    {
        if(ptr->right != NULL)
        {
            ptr->right = InsertPriv(data, ptr->right);
        }
        else
        {
            ptr->right = CreateNode(data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "duplicate data cannot be entered" << std::endl;
    }

    // Update the balance factor of each node and
    // balance the tree
    ptr->height = 1 + max(height(ptr->left),
                          height(ptr->right));
    int balanceFactor = getBalanceFactor(ptr);
    if (balanceFactor > 1) {
        if (data < ptr->left->data) {
            return rightRotate(ptr);
        } else if (data > ptr->left->data) {
            ptr->left = leftRotate(ptr->left);
            return rightRotate(ptr);
        }
    }
    if (balanceFactor < -1) {
        if (data > ptr->right->data) {
            return leftRotate(ptr);
        } else if (data < ptr->right->data) {
            ptr->right = rightRotate(ptr->right);
            return leftRotate(ptr);
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}



// Node with minimum value
template <class T>
node<T>* nodeWithMimumValue(node<T>* ptr) {
    node<T>* current = ptr;
    while (current->left != NULL)
        current = current->left;
    return current;
}

/**
 * @brief Search the binary search tree for the value specified
 * @tparam T
 * @param data The data that you want to search for
 */

template <class T>
bool Bst<T>::Search(T data)
{
   return SearchPriv(this->root, data);
}

/**
 * @brief Traverse though the binary search tree and process nodes in order
 * @tparam T
 * @param process The function for processing
 */
template <class T>
using Process = void (*)(T&, std::vector<T>&);

template <class T>
void Bst<T>::InOrder(Process<T> process, std::vector<T> &dataVec)
{
    InOrderPriv(root, *process, dataVec);
}

/**
 * @brief Traverse though the binary search tree and process nodes in post order
 * @tparam T
 * @param process
 */
template <class T>
void Bst<T>::PostOrder(void (*process)(T& node))
{
    PostOrderPriv(root, *process);
}

/**
 * @brief Traverse though the binary search tree and process nodes in pre order
 * @tparam T
 * @param process
 */
template <class T>
void Bst<T>::PreOrder(void (*process)(T& node))
{
    PreOrderPriv(root, *process);
}
/**
 * @brief Private
 * @tparam T
 * @param ptr
 * @param process
 */
template <class T>
void Bst<T>::PreOrderPriv(node<T>* ptr, void (*process)(T& node))
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        // go process node
        (*process)(ptr->data);

        // go left
        if(ptr->left != NULL)
        {
            PreOrderPriv(ptr->left, *process);
        }

        // go right
        if(ptr->right != NULL)
        {
            PreOrderPriv(ptr->right, *process);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Tree is empty." << std::endl;
    }
}

template <class T>
void Bst<T>::PostOrderPriv(node<T>* ptr, void (*process)(T& node))
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        // go left
        if(ptr->left !=NULL)
        {
            PostOrderPriv(ptr->left, *process);
        }

        // go right
        if(ptr->right !=NULL)
        {
            PostOrderPriv(ptr->right, *process);
        }

        // process node
        (*process)(ptr->data);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Tree is empty." << std::endl;
    }

}

// overload this function so that it can take a function pointer that retrieves a node + vector
template <class T>
void Bst<T>::InOrderPriv(node<T> *ptr, void (*process)(T &, std::vector<T> &), std::vector<T> & dataVec)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        // go left
        if(ptr->left != NULL)
        {
            InOrderPriv(ptr->left, *process, dataVec);
        }

        // process node
        (*process)(ptr->data, dataVec);

        // go right
        if(ptr->right !=NULL)
        {
            InOrderPriv(ptr->right, *process, dataVec);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Tree is empty." << std::endl;
    }
}

template <class T>
bool Bst<T>::SearchPriv(node<T>* ptr, T data)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        if(ptr->data == data)
        {
            std::cout << "The data has been found." << std::endl;
            return true;
        }
        else if(ptr->data < data)
        {
            SearchPriv(ptr->left, data);
        }
        else
        {
            SearchPriv(ptr->right, data);
        }
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot be found. " << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}

template <class T>
void Bst<T>::DeleteTree()
{
    Delete(root);
}

template <class T>
void Bst<T>::Delete(node<T>* &ptr)
{
    if(ptr != nullptr)
    {
        Delete(ptr->left);
        Delete(ptr->right);

        delete ptr;

        ptr = nullptr;
    }
}

template <class T>
void Bst<T>::CopyTree(node<T>* lhsRoot, node<T>* rhsRoot)
{
    if(rhsRoot == nullptr)
    {
        lhsRoot = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        lhsRoot = new node<T>;
        lhsRoot->data = rhsRoot->data;

        CopyTree(lhsRoot->left, rhsRoot->left);
        CopyTree(lhsRoot->right, rhsRoot->right);
    }
}

/**
 * @brief FROM PROGRAMIZ - Calculate height
 * @tparam T
 * @param ptr
 * @return
 */
template <class T>
int height(node<T>* ptr) {
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return 0;
    return ptr->height;
}
/**
 * @brief FROM PROGRAMIZ - Calculate max
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @return
 */
template <class T>
int Bst<T>::max(int a, int b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

/**
 * @brief FROM PROGRAMIZ - Rotate right
 * @tparam T
 * @param y
 * @return
 */

template <class T>
node<T>* Bst<T>::rightRotate(node<T>* y) {
    node<T> *x = y->left;
    node<T> *T2 = x->right;
    x->right = y;
    y->left = T2;
    y->height = max(height(y->left),
                    height(y->right)) +
                1;
    x->height = max(height(x->left),
                    height(x->right)) +
                1;
    return x;
}

/**
 * @brief FROM PROGRAMIZ - Rotate left
 * @tparam T
 * @param x
 * @return
 */
template <class T>
node<T>* Bst<T>::leftRotate(node<T>* x) {
    node<T>* y = x->right;
    node<T>* T2 = y->left;
    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;
    x->height = max(height(x->left),
                    height(x->right)) +
                1;
    y->height = max(height(y->left),
                    height(y->right)) +
                1;
    return y;
}



// assignment operator overload
template <class T>
Bst<T>& Bst<T>::operator=(Bst<T>& rhs)
{
    if (this == &rhs) return *this; // handle self assignment

    //assignment operator
    CopyTree(this->root, rhs.root);

    return *this;
}

#endif //UNTITLED_BST_H
```

Comment: `lhsRoot` in `CopyTree` is a local variable. Changes to it are not visible outside the function. The function allocates a bunch of nodes that are then promptly leaked because the caller has no way to actually access them. After the call `CopyTree(this->root, rhs.root);`, `this->root` remains unchanged; in your example, it's still null.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in my code!

The thing that fixed it was that, in my CopyTree func, I was passing it in by pointer, and not by pointer reference

```cpp
// old
void CopyTree(node<T>* lhsRoot, node<T>* rhsRoot);

// correct
void CopyTree(node<T>*& lhsRoot, node<T>* rhsRoot);
```